# Para que sirve "=>" en C#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es para que se utilizan los caracteres => en C#, lo he visto en un método para acceder al sensor de luz del dispositivo.
Este es el método

```
private void _lightSensor_ReadingChanged(LightSensor sender, LightSensorReadingChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        _dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Lux = args.Reading.IlluminanceInLux;
        });

        Debug.WriteLine("Lux: {0}", Lux);
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Ve algo acerca de "Lambda"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En c# el operador `=>` se conoce como operador lambda.

Sirve para crear un `Func<>`, `Action<>` o `Expression<Func<>>` según se necesite.

En tu caso

```
() =>
    {
        Lux = args.Reading.IlluminanceInLux;
    }
```

Es equivalente a un método parecido a este

```
void MetodoAPasarleAlRunAsync()
{
    Lux = args.Reading.IlluminanceInLux;
}
```

A la izquierda del `=>` van la lista de argumentos en este caso vacío y la derecha el bloque de código a ejecutar.

Como a la izquierda solo hay un par de paréntesis vacíos el método no tiene parámetros y como el bloque de código no devuelve nada su tipo de retorno será `void`

Answer (score 6):

**Operador lambda =>**

> El token => se denomina operador lambda. **Se utiliza en expresiones
>   lambda para separar las variables de entrada del lado izquierdo del
>   cuerpo lambda del lado derecho.** Las expresiones lambda son expresiones
>   insertadas similares a los métodos anónimos, pero más flexibles; se
>   utilizan mucho en las consultas de LINQ que se expresan en la sintaxis
>   del método.Para obtener más información, vea Expresiones lambda (Guía
>   de programación de C#).

**[Documentación operador = > en Español.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb311046.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

Es una expresión u operador lambda lo mismo que dijo mi compañero ahí arriba, hace parte de los operadores de programación funcional en c# y otros lenguajes, es una forma mas abreviada de escribir una función, además de que permite crear reglas mas simples, es decir, aportando a lo ya mencionado en este te digo que puedes validar objetos, puedes declarar axiomas que luego serán ejecutados.

```
internal static readonly Predicate<objetParaValidacion>[] Validation =
{
    (x) => x.Id != null && x.Id != "",
    (x) => x.CropId != null && x.CropId != "",
};
```

Entonces, si te das cuenta puedes hacer eso con este tipo de funciones, en ves de utilizar un montón de `if-else` puedes hacer una coleccionen de funciones que validen el estado de un objeto. evita código espagueti.

Esto es para que veas el potencial que tiene este tipo de programación y su utilidad, sin embargo, es solo un ejemplo de todo lo que se puede lograr hacer utilizando esto.

No trato de explicarte  todo este paradigma en un solo ejemplo eso seria imposible, pero  te digo con este ejemplo  una utilidad  y valor que puede llegar a conseguir si la aprendes.